# Get the values at memory addresses

Tags: c++, c, memory

I am working on a file operation project in C++. I am trying to print the memory and cpu usage of my current process in my program. I get some reference help from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682050(v=vs.85).aspx)
But its printing the memory addresses used by the process. All I want is to get the value of the memory usage at that address. I tried to use through pointers but didnot succeed.

Here by doing this, it prints the memory address of the process.

```
 printf( "\tPeakPagefileUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.PageFaultCount );
```

Thats ok,
but then I tried to print the value at that address. it gives exception

```
unsigned int *jk;
*jk=pmc.PageFaultCount;
        cout<<"\n"<<jk<<"\n";
```

May be I am using the wrong data type to hold the memory address in jk.
But I m not sure, what the problem is. PLz guide me to fix this

Comment: u r rite ,in c++ we also do the same thing                                   int m=9;
   int *b;
   
   b=&m;
   cout<<*b; . This thing gives me the exact value at the address but when I tried with above code it gives error therefore I went with *jk=pmc.PageFaultCount

Comment: To print a pointer using [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) you should use the `"%p"` format, and a `void *` type.

Comment: Are you wanting the address of `pmc.PageFaultCount`? If so use `jk = &pmc.PageFaultCount;`.

Comment: `*jk=pmc.PageFaultCount;` This wrong as `jk` is uninitialized.

Comment: The `printf` doesn't print an address, it prints the integer `pmc.PageFaultCount` in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

You never allocated `jk` (horrible name). You can either use automatic storage:

```
unsigned int jk=pmc.PageFaultCount;
```

Or you can allocate memory yourself:

```
unsigned int *jk=new unsigned int;             // or malloc for C
*jk=pmc.PageFaultCount;


// and sometime later
delete jk;                                     // or free in C
```

As a side note, don't confuse C with C++. They're two separate languages.

Comment: Why dynamically allocate an integer??

Comment: Don't ask me, it's his fetish!

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the variable `jk`

```
unsigned int *jk;
```

you don't initialize it, so its value is *indeterminate*.

Then when you in the next line *dereference* the pointer, then you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should not dereference `jk` when you assign to it.

If `pmc.PageFaultCount` itself is not a pointer, then you need to use the address-of operator `&` to get a pointer to it.

---

However, if you want to print the pointer to `pmc.PageFaultCount`, then you don't need a temporary variable to store it in, just print it:

```
std::cout << "Pointer to PageFaultCount = " << static_cast<void*>(&pmc.PageFaultCount) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think this is a pointer? [`PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms684877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains *counts*, not addresses.

Use it like this:

```
std::cout << "Page fault count: " << pmc.PageFaultCount << std::endl;
```

Comment: it contains the memory addresses, those addresses must have some values

Comment: @ArsalanSherwani The structure contains `DWORD`s and `SIZE_T`s, not addresses. [See the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: But they do have some values , stored on them. I want those values

Comment: I don't understand. When you execute `std::cout << pmc.PageFaultCount`, it displays the page fault count. Is this not what you needed?

Comment: yes now I get, the values were in bytes . Using cout will print them as int values .

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea regarding `C++` or `C#`, buit in case of `c`

```
unsigned int *jk;
*jk=pmc.PageFaultCount;
```

will give segfault because `jk` is unintialized here.

Instead, you can do

```
unsigned int *jk = malloc(sizeof(int));
*jk=pmc.PageFaultCount;
```

Comment: Why the heck malloc an integer??

Comment: @NeilKirk to tell OP where exactly the mistake was.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems with the format specifier:

```
printf( "\tPeakPagefileUsage: 0x%08X\n", pmc.PeakPagefileUsage );
```

Try using

```
printf( "\tPeakPagefileUsage: 0x%08d\n", pmc.PeakPagefileUsage );
```

The first one is printing in hexa-decimal (base 16) format, but you may like to print it in decimal (base-10) format.

EDIT: Or better use **%64d** to print 64-bit integer.

Comment: Or use C++ as tagged, and let the compiler figure out how many bits there are.

Comment: For logging, writing to console, sending over wire, printf-family of function are still better choice!

Comment: printf("\n Page Fault Count : %d", pmc.WorkingSetSize);                      cout<<"Page Fault Count is: "<<*jk<<"\n";                           The both results are different, I dont know why